# C# .txt file: Reading a substring in next line if previous line contains "X"

Tags: c#, text-files

I am looking to read from a text file and if a line contains "XYZ" I need to return substrings within that line, then have the next line read for another substring.

There will be several lines that will return the "XYZ" and on each of these I will require the substring from the following line (Each of these will be a different value).
Currently I can return all instances of the substrings in the lines with "XYZ" but then either keep returning the same substring (which should be unique each time) from the line below the first "XYZ" or just, as below, each character individually.

So in the below snippet, from the log. If a line contains XYZ then I need to move to the next line and pull the Date/Time/and Batch Name Number. 
XYZ will repeat several times through out the log, with different results each time.

2015-07-02 11:03:13,838 [1] INFO Place (null) (null) (null) – btnAction_Click, Completed Scan for _HAH_Claim_T, ***XYZ***

**2015-07-02** **11:03:14,432** [1] INFO Place (null) (null) (null) – btnAction_Click, Set batch name ***1234567***

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"Text Document.txt");


        foreach (string line in lines)
        {
            int success = line.IndexOf("XYZ");

            if (success > 0)
            {
                string pass = "Pass";
                string date = line.Substring(0, 10);
                string time = line.Substring(11, 12);
                int ID = line.LastIndexOf("XYZ");

                if (ID != 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("\n\t" + pass + " Date: {0}\tTime: {1}", date, time);
                }

                string currentLine;
                string batchID;

                for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
                {

                    currentLine = lines.Skip(6).First();

                    batchID = currentLine.Substring(100);
                    Console.WriteLine("\tBatchID{0}", batchID[i]);
                }

                Console.WriteLine();
            }



        }


        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit.");
        System.Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: So, what's the problem?

Comment: Can you provide an example of text-file (2 lines are enough) and then mark the strings you need?

Comment: Why are you always using the seventh line as your current line for the batch id?

Comment: 2015-07-02 11:03:13,838 [1] INFO  Place (null) (null) (null) – Scan, verifyMsg:  (Pages:34 Separators: 9)

2015-07-02 11:03:13,838 [1] INFO  Place (null) (null) (null) – Scan method end

**2015-07-02** **11:03:13,838** [1] INFO  AbTranScan (null) (null) (null) – btnAction_Click, Completed Scan for _HAH_Claim_T, **XYZ**

2015-07-02 11:03:14,432 [1] INFO  Place (null) (null) (null) – btnAction_Click, Set batch name **1234567**

Comment: Need Date, Time and Batch Name. It is a log file so the format repeats hence the locked references

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not completely understand the question as it is a bit abstract as to what you want to extract from each line but something like this will hopefully get you on the right track

```
    using (var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
    {
        while (!reader.EndOfStream)
        {
            var line = reader.ReadLine();
            if (line.Contains("XYZ") && !reader.EndOfStream)
            {
                var nextLine = reader.ReadLine();
                var pass = "Pass";
                var date = nextLine.Substring(0, 10);
                var time = nextLine.Substring(11, 12);

                Console.WriteLine("\n\t" + pass + " Date: {0}\tTime: {1}", date, time);
            }
        }
    }
```

the line variable is the one containing XYZ and next line is the line subsequent to that. If this is not meeting you requirements the please update the question to be a bit more specific

Answer (score 0):

I would say something like this?

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"Text Document.txt");

for(int i = 0; i < lines.Length(); i++){
    if(lines[i].Contains("XYZ")){
        string pass = "Pass";
        string date = line.Substring(0, 10);
        string time = line.Substring(11, 12);
        Console.WriteLine("\n\t" + pass + " Date: {0}\tTime: {1}", date, time);

        // Retrieve the value in the next line
        string nextLineAfterXYZ = lines[i + 1];
        batchID = nextLineAfterXYZ.Substring(100);
        Console.WriteLine("\tBatchID{0}", batchID);
    }
}
```

You should add some error-handling, in case it's the last line (IndexOutOfBound) etc.

Comment: batchID=currentLine.Substring(100) keeps stating that currentLine doesn't exist

Comment: Should be 'nextLineAfterXYZ' sorry.

Comment: @greenhoorn - I corrected your post per the comments.  If I have made an error please correct it.

Answer (score -3):

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"E:Sum.txt");
string str = string.Empty;
foreach (string line in lines)
{
    if (line.Contains("x"))
    {
        str += line;                   
        Console.WriteLine();
        continue;
    }
    break;
}

Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit.");
System.Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: Please put your code inside code blocks, by prepending lines with a TAB, and also try to place some comment with your code, as to explain what you did and why you did it.

Comment: Code only answers are discouraged.